# Running celery in django not as an external process?

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I want to give celery a try. I'm interested in a simple way to schedule crontab-like tasks, similar to Spring's quartz.

I see from celery's documentation that it requires running `celeryd` as a daemon process. Is there a way to refrain from running another external process and simply running this embedded in my django instance? Since I'm not interested in distributing the work at the moment, I'd rather keep it simple.

Comment: You are trying to find a way around launching with `python manage.py celeryd` using celery-django? I don't believe there's any such option.

Comment: ...not to forget `python manage.py celerybeat` if you also care about your periodical tasks...

Answer (score 0):

Add [CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER=True](http://ask.github.com/celery/configuration.html#celery-always-eager) option in your django settings file and all your tasks will be executed locally. Seems like for the periodic tasks you have to execute celery beat as well.

Comment: This makes it so that tasks happen synchronously, and just seems to lose the whole effect I was hoping for... But thanks!

Comment: You could try to execute celeryd as a process together with runserver, for example, from your code, using [manage.py functionality](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#running-management-commands-from-your-code).